# Include first line with AWK and set output based on filename

Tags: awk, grep, cat

`cat /path/to/file1 /path/to/file2 | awk '{if ($3~/^TCF/ || $3~/^GLI/) print $0;}' > /path/to/test1.txt`

Do you know how to:

Include the first row in file1 in the test1.txt output?
And, is it possible to include if TCF and GLI came from file1 or file2?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can be shorten some

```
awk '{if ($3~/^TCF|^GLI/ || NR==1 ) print $0,FILENAME}' /path/to/file1 /path/to/file2 > /path/to/test1.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this command:

```
 awk '$3~/^TCF/ || $3~/^GLI/ || NR==1 { print FILENAME, $0 }' /path/to/file1 /path/to/file2 > /path/to/test1.txt
```

- **`NR`** is the current record number in the total input stream.
- **`FILENAME`** is the name of the current input file.

Comment: I would add `{print FILENAME, $0}` to show the file name, as per the second question.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{
      if ($3~/^TCF/ || $3~/^GLI/ || NR==1 ) 
      print $0,FILENAME
     }' /path/to/file1 /path/to/file2 >/path/to/test1.txt
```